# Mysql instalation process interrupted when it doesnt finished

Tags: mysql, linux-mint

I'm trying to install mysql-server, php,apache2,and phpmyadmin on my Sarah. But I got error in installing phpmyadmin so I suggested to clear all the package. When I reinstall mysql-server someone close my terminal when the process isn't finished. So how do i repair the 'unfinished' installation?